# Conditional GAN training

Tags: neural-networks, sampling, gan

Quite a simple question about [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.1784.pdf):
How is the cGAN trained? I'm interested in the Pix2Pix network

In particular, given the batch approach, given a specific step, is this the correct procedure?

1. sample $(x,y_{real})$ from the dataset, generate $y_{fake}$ using the generator
2. give to the discriminator $(x,y_{real})$ and $(x,y_{fake})$ and ask him to discriminate the fake ones

Or to the discriminator, we have to give him a set of $(x,y_{real})$ different to the ones given to the generator?